# How to display and hide ng template based on events?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to show the view and clear the same based on the `click` and `dblclick` events.
On click of the *paragraph* changing initial background to *red* from *yellow* and trying to create view.

On double click changing background to *green* from *red* and trying to clear view.
I'm able to change the colors but not able to create and clear the view.

Below is my code

**html:**

```
<p appBasic [tempref]="basicDirContent">Content of paragraph</p>
<ng-template #basicDirContent>
  <h6>Paragraph content clicked</h6>
</ng-template>
```

**directive**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBasic]'
})
export class BasicDirective  {
  @Input() tempref: TemplateRef<any>;
  
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') bgColor = 'yellow';

  constructor(
    private viewCR: ViewContainerRef
    ) { }


  @HostListener('click') click(e: Event ): void {
    this.bgColor = 'red';
    this.viewCR.createEmbeddedView(this.tempref);
  }
  @HostListener('dblclick') dblclick(e: Event ): void {
    this.bgColor = 'green';
    this.viewCR.clear();
  }
}
```

Please let me know what is the issue here!!

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing? I created a stackblitz for this and everything seems to be working fine for me - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bxed7n